# Is User::create() safe in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, user-input, mass-assignment

I'm trying to make my Laravel `UserController` as lean as possible without using any additional packages, like Ardent (I find it unnecessary; overkill.)

This is my `postRegister()` function, the function that is routed to when the user clicks "submit" on the registration form.

```
public function postRegister() {
    $validator = new Services\Validators\RUser;
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        User::create(Input::all());
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
    return Redirect::to('register')->withInput()->withErrors($validator->getErrors());
}
```

I sent all the input off to be validated in another class, then I just call the class statically with `User::create()`. I'm wondering if this is safe or not. I'm having everything but the `id` and `password_confirmation` mass-assigned, and the password is hashed in a mutator function.

If this isn't a safe way to handle user creation, how else should I do it? Should I instead create an instance of the object and manually assign values? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the Model::Create function does these steps:

1. Instantiate a new model instance
2. Using the input array, fill in all unguarded/fillable model attributes using set-mutators if available
3. Save model to DB
4. Return model

So as long as you add the fields that you don't want to be mass-assigned to your $guarded array (or excluded them from your $fillable array) there shouldn't be any security risks. The functionality is about the same as building the model gradually and then saving it.

As a recommendation: The input validation should happen within the model during either the "saving" or "creating" event. If you return false during one of those events, you'll halt the model creation.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Going onto your recommendation, how would I go about that exactly? Should I call the User::create() function and then do something inside of the model? Not sure how I would do that.

Comment: Essentially when calling the Save method, the following events are triggered in order: Saving > Creating or Updating > Created or Updated > Saved. The Create function calls Save after the model is filled in with the attributes. You can see an example of how this is done in the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events. As a side-note, the Create function will return the model whether or not it saves to the database. So to perform your conditional redirect, you may want to avoid it and call Save yourself so you can check the return boolean. Lot of options.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for that link, I see how I can hook into it now.

Comment: If you want to cut down on which Input get's passed (instead of `Input::all()`), you can use `Input::only()`. Example: `Input::only(array('username', 'password', 'email'))`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you populate the models `$fillable` array with only the values you want mass-assignable this is safe. Validating all the `$fillable` values then adds the safe-guard you're asking about.

This ensures that only the values in `$fillable` are ever populated on the model with any other Input disregarded.